# Killer 1535 and E2400 NIC Support in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: wireless

Is Killer -n/a/ac 1535 and E2400 Gigabit ethernet now supported out of the box? Killer's website says "latest Kernel updates are supported natively"!

Can someone please confirm?

Comment: Last year's "latest kernel" isn't today's "latest kernel", so you will have to figure out which version they actually mean, and compare that to the one in Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with these damned Killer NICs! They don't specify...

However, Ubuntu 16.04 is running 4.4, if I am not wrong... does 4.4 include the 1535 drivers? I am guessing I will still have to add the firmware myself?

Any info on 1535 status on Kernel 4.4 would be useful!

Comment: @SamuelS.Mandal It does include but for me it doesn't work. Ridiculous. https://askubuntu.com/questions/794218/getting-killer-wireless-ac-1535-working-for-installing-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, even with Kernel 4.10.0.x you still need to get the Killer 1525/1535 firmware by yourself, and then compile and modprob them before your wireless is up and running. For this, since you need to be connected to the internet, I recommend getting a small USB wifi dongle. Either temporarily, or keep one handy for re-installation scenarios. Because if you have Killer ethernet as well, plugging in a fiber connection won't help.

Good news, however, is that the above is the hardest part of the process. Once you have a running internet connection, just run the following codes one by one, and your wifi will be up and running before you can say "contemporaneities" !

```
wget mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb

sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link from Killer's website: http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/20-killer-wireless-ac-in-linux-ubuntu-debian It says, in part:

> Killer 1525 and 1535 use the ath10k driver which is included in the
>   latest kernel updates.

It then gives instructions to download and install the board-specific firmware. There are many questions and accepted answers on this site about ath10k_pci and firmware. Although I haven't the device myself, I expect that the process is trivial.

The ethernet has a page as well: http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/21-killer-e2400-in-linux-ubuntu-debian It shows how to amend the source code to add the device ID of 1969:e0a1. The device ID is covered by default in 16.04 and should work with no additional effort.

This answer applies to kernel version 4.4.xx and later.

Comment: Alrighty! I'm guessing, then, that adding the firmware should fix the wifi!! And the ethernet, as you point out, is covered already!

Now, to kick the free spyware that is Windows 10 to the ninth layer of hell where it belongs!

Comment: It is easy enough to try the live session DVD or USB and confirm that the ethernet is working. If so, you could even download and install the firmware; all without making any permanent changes.

Comment: The ethernet might need the MTU set to 8192 if it doesn't work with 16.04 as there is a bug that was fixed recently in the alx module

Comment: Just trying to install Ubuntu Studio 16.05, kernel 4.4.0-21. Yeah, the wireless would work if I had wired connection. The kernel contains firmware files, but they don't work. Using the github's firmware files also don't help. More details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/794218/getting-killer-wireless-ac-1535-working-for-installing-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

I'm running 4.4.0.36 kernel, Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller, Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter. The last is Killer 1535. Both ran out of the box. Hope that helps.