# cron.daily hanging my system?

Tags: 16.04, cron, anacron

It happens about once a week and the system completely freezes. Doesn't react to Ctrl+Alt+F1, Ctrl+Alt+Delete, I need to hard reset it. Despite it happens different time of the day, every time I check the last message is from CRON:

```
Dec 20 08:17:01 titan CRON[4106]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

`/etc/cron.hourly` is empty, there's just a `.placeholder` in it. I executed every task in `/etc/cron.daily` manually, but neither of them caused a crash that time.

How can I debug this further? I don't see any detailed logs about cron. Should I place log writes in the cron jobs? Is there any other place where daily or hourly cron jobs can be picked up besides `/etc/cron.hourly` and `/etc/cron.daily`?

I'm running 16.04 Ubuntu Studio, with Xfce. I had trouble before with my wifi ([Getting Killer Wireless-AC 1535 working for installing Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794218/getting-killer-wireless-ac-1535-working-for-installing-ubuntu-16-04)) and even with the install to btrfs based RAID 0 NVMe setup, I don't suspect these though this time.

Comment: my `/etc/cron.hourly` has no `.placeholder` in it. Perhaps you should delete `.placeholder`?

Comment: `.placeholder` should be pretty harmless. It's ignored and just there to avoid the deletion of the folder.

Comment: As I don't have a `.placehoder` it was hard to know for sure. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cron is not hanging your system.** The log is misleading you.

Every hour, the `cron` job runs and adds that line to your log, before running the commands in `/etc/cron.hourly`.

Just because it is the last line in your log does not mean the program that wrote that line is the culprit of the system hang. This is actually the opposite: at the time `cron` ran (at 08:17:01), you can be quite sure your system was working fine.

Since `cron` runs this task every hour, all you know from the log is that the hang happened some time between 08:17:01 and 09:17:01.

Most programs run without creating a single line in the log. It actually takes some (programming) effort to write a line in the log; a log entry is a *feature* of the program that wrote it; it is not surveillance data written by the system to ensure programs are well behaved.

Most programs cannot hang the machine either. Most machine hangs are caused by faulty hardware and kernel driver issues. This is what you should investigate, especially with your hardware (Wi-Fi that needs specific firmware, NVMe that is still getting patches in Ubuntu, etc.).

Comment: It's indeed a possibility that it's not a CRON job. I don't see any kernel panic or anything which would point me to any direction unfortunately. Is there a way to switch the kernel to more verbose logging mode?