# Killer 1535 802.11ac 2x2 on Dell XPS 13 kaby lake not working under Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, dell, 16.10

I have a Dell XPS 13 Kaby Lake, running Ubuntu 16.10.

The wireless card in this device is "Killer 1535 802.11ac 2x2 WiFi and Bluetooth 4.1".

Lately, I'm having increasingly severe problems connecting to a network, to the point where I can currently not access the internet at all. I've tried the solution here [Getting Killer Wireless-AC 1535 working for installing Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794218/getting-killer-wireless-ac-1535-working-for-installing-ubuntu-16-04), but it's not working for my machine.  I used the latest version available at the time of writing (1.162).

I'm getting 2 warnings (`possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/... for module i915`) on running `modprobe`. After rebooting, `dmesg` lines containing `ath` are:

```
[   40.976042] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   40.999663] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   41.280248] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   41.280261] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   41.280756] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   41.280760] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   41.283081] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[   41.283084] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   41.283513] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
[   41.349058] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 6fc88fe7
[   43.496457] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   43.581127] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[   43.581128] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   43.581130] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   43.581130] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   43.585473] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
[   55.450429] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[   55.450434] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   55.450435] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   55.450436] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   55.450437] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[   55.450437] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   55.450438] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
```

Notice the firmware messages at 41.280.

What could I do? I'm willing to do a downgrade to 16.04 if it would help.

Some other observations:

- I AM connected to the networks that I try to connect to, it seems, and the device is assigned an IPv4 address.
- Entering an url in firefox is not loading anything, however. Also `ping`ing won't return anything.
- Even though I was able to access the internet when I first installed 16.10, I currently cannot access any sites *even when using a clean live USB* to "try out Ubuntu".

Here is a screenshot showing that a network is connected, but nothing is coming through ping:

[image]

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: The i915 message is harmless and not relevant to wireless.

Comment: Does anyone else have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I suggest is to update the firmware. With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.162_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.162_all.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if connectivity has improved. If you are still having issues, please show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I've added the information to the question. There's no improvements in connectivitiy

Comment: Please see my edit above. The firmware messages you pointed out are not significant. It says, in effect, I looked for firmware A but didn't find it; I looked for firmware B and didn't find it and then I looked for firmware C, found it and loaded it. As we just upgraded to the latest available firmware, we must assume it is optimum.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I think you're thought, that it might be the router's settings, is at least partly correct: of the 2 networks here, one usually works temporarily, the other one never works. I checked the settings of  the latter, but they are all already as described. A reboot didn't help.

Comment: Also changing to a specific regulatory domain didn't help.

Comment: Neither did disabling IPv6. Do you have other suggestions? I added some additional information concerning Ethernet, which is present in the network selection window, but not present on the laptop. Many thanks

Comment: Is the ethernet device not managed by Network Manager because it is declared in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: That file only contains `auto lo \n   
iface lo inet loopback`. (`\n` is newline) I've found that the entries are not present when I boot the machine, and get added once I start up a Windows VM. I assume it has no bearing on the problem at hand.